# Here Tracking API Forbidden! The account does not have the correct privileges

Tags: authorization, here-api

I am working with HERE Tracking API and I am getting a 403 error.
I am getting the access token using two different requests: https://tracking.api.here.com/users/v2/login
or https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token.
In both cases in which I receive the token, it does not work for a request like https://tracking.api.here.com/shipments.
I am getting an error like this:
{
"code": 403,
"id": "553a8329-d3f8-449e-965b-5873f748814c",
"message": "Principal doesn't have access to the resource",
"error": "Forbidden \ n \ nThe account does not have the correct privileges \ n"
}

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tracking REST API are excluded from Freemium and Pro. Please [contact](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you) us if you are interested.

Further details about Freemium or a Pro Plan with HERE and where you can find your plan inclusions and terms can be found [here](https://knowledge.here.com/csm_kb?id=public_kb_csm_details&number=KB0017827)